# How to self update a component after an async api call has completed?

Tags: reactjs

This is my current code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends Component {

    test: boolean | null = null;
    
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.fetchCurrentChargingStatus();
    }

    async fetchCurrentChargingStatus(){
        const result = await fetch("some url");
        this.test = (await result.text()) == "true"
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button>{this.test == null ? "null" : this.test ? "True" : "False"}</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

I make a REST-API call when this component is loaded. Depending on the result, I want to update the text of the button. How can this be achieved?

Comment: For starters, dont call your method in constructor, you must use componentDidMount or any lifecycle method that suits your use case.

Next up, once your method is called you are setting the values in this reference of the component, whereas, it will be better to declare a state and then use setState to mutate the state.

Comment: Once your state is initialized, you can use the same approach you are using, instead of `this.test` you will use `this.state.test` to get the desired value

Comment: You should use something like `componentDidMount() {this.setState({ isLoading: true });` and `this.setState({ isLoading: false});}`, `render() {
  if (!this.state.isLoading) {
    return null; // or any fallback UI
  }

  return (
   // the original UI
  )
}`